# Return index value datetime.now.dayofweek but how?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

is there any function of datetime return dayofweekindex? such as:
int Todaywhat_is_Index= = DateTime.Now.IndexOfDayofThisWeek;
if Today is friday, it must be return 5
ifToday is Saturday, it must be return 6
ifToday is Sunday, it must be return 0

Comment: If you want it faster : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22278311/3315914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx).

Please note this depends on the regional settings (here in Europe Monday is the first day of the week).

Comment: Be warned: this value varies by culture.  Depending on where you are day 0 may be either Sunday or Monday.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to cast it back to an int to get it as a number.

Comment: Use DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.DayNames to avoid culture

Comment: @GerrieSchenck I know your comment was made some years ago so perhaps things have changed but the current doc states: If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday). No mention of any regional/culture variances.

Answer (score 17):

This little one-liner works independent of locale, with always Friday == 5

```
int x = (int)System.Globalization.CultureInfo
        .InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 int dayOfWeek;
 dayOfWeek = (int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - (int)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + 1
```